# List sorting compile error

Tags: c#, list, sorting, asp.net-3.5, hashset

I am trying to get an unique, alphabetized list of industry names (strings). Here is my code:

```
HashSet<string> industryHash = new HashSet<string>();
List<string> industryList = new List<string>();
List<string> orderedIndustries = new List<string>();

// add a few items to industryHash

industryList = industryHash.ToList<string>();
orderedIndustries = industryList.Sort(); //throws compilation error
```

The last line throws a compilation error:
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: While you're at it, you may as well use an OrderedSet btw. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx) sorts the original list and does not return a new one. So either use this method or `Enumerable.OrderBy + ToList`:

efficient:

```
industryList.Sort();
```

less efficient:

```
industryList = industryList.OrderBy(s => s).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Sort is a void method, you can't retrieve a value from this method. You can look on [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b0zbh7b6.aspx)

You can use [OrderBy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966.aspx) to order your list

Comment: The article you referenced is in French.

Answer (score 1):

It sorts the list in-place. If you want a copy, use `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 1):

Do this :

```
HashSet<string> industryHash = new HashSet<string>();
List<string> industryList = new List<string>();

// add a few items to industryHash

industryList = industryHash.ToList<string>();
List<string> orderedIndustries = new List<string>(industryList.Sort());
```

Note : that don't keep the unsorted list, so no real point over doing just industryList.Sort()

Comment: No, I don't. I just didn't realize that I can sort the list without making a copy.

Comment: Well, you're all set then ^^

Answer (score 0):

One option is using LINQ and removing `industryList`:

```
HashSet<string> industryHash = new HashSet<string>();
//List<string> industryList = new List<string>();
List<string> orderedIndustries = new List<string>();

orderedIndustries = (from s in industryHash
                     orderby s
                     select s).ToList();
```